# python pandas: vectorized function value error "lengths do not match"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
'customer_id','transaction_dt','product','price','units'
1,2004-01-02 00:00:00,thing1,25,47
1,2004-01-17 00:00:00,thing2,150,8
2,2004-01-29 00:00:00,thing2,150,25
3,2017-07-15 00:00:00,thing3,55,17
3,2016-05-12 00:00:00,thing3,55,47
4,2012-02-23 00:00:00,thing2,150,22
4,2009-10-10 00:00:00,thing1,25,12
4,2014-04-04 00:00:00,thing2,150,2
5,2008-07-09 00:00:00,thing2,150,43
5,2004-01-30 00:00:00,thing1,25,40
5,2004-01-31 00:00:00,thing1,25,22
5,2004-02-01 00:00:00,thing1,25,2
```

And I have written the following to apply date range columns:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start_date_period = pd.period_range('2004-01-01', '12-31-2017', freq='30D')
end_date_period = pd.period_range('2004-01-30', '12-31-2017', freq='30D')

def find_window_start_date(x):
    window_start_date_idx = np.argmax(x < start_date_period.end_time)
    return start_date_period[window_start_date_idx]

df['window_start_dt'] = df['transaction_dt'].apply(find_window_start_date)

def find_window_end_date(x):
    window_end_date_idx = np.argmin(x > end_date_period.start_time)
    return end_date_period[window_end_date_idx]

df['window_end_dt'] = df['transaction_dt'].apply(find_window_end_date)
```

However this is very slow, so I have been trying to vectorize it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start_date_period = pd.period_range('2004-01-01', '12-31-2017', freq='30D')
end_date_period = pd.period_range('2004-01-30', '12-31-2017', freq='30D')

def find_window_start_date(x):
    window_start_date_idx = np.argmax(x < start_date_period.end_time)
    return start_date_period[window_start_date_idx]

df['window_start_dt'] = find_window_start_date(df['transaction_dt'].values)

def find_window_end_date(x):
    window_end_date_idx = np.argmin(x > end_date_period.start_time)
    return end_date_period[window_end_date_idx]

df['window_end_dt'] = find_window_end_date(df['transaction_dt'].values)
```

However this produces a value error: "Lengths must match to compare".  I am new to trying to write vectorized functions from scratch, so I would appreciate any insight into where I am going awry.

**EDIT:**

Here is the full error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a781075467c5> in <module>()
      5     return start_date_period[window_start_date_idx]
      6 
----> 7 df['window_start_dt'] = find_window_start_date(df['transaction_dt'].values)
      8 
      9 def find_window_end_date(x):

<ipython-input-11-a781075467c5> in find_window_start_date(x)
      2 
      3 def find_window_start_date(x):
----> 4     window_start_date_idx = np.argmax(x < start_date_period.end_time)
      5     return start_date_period[window_start_date_idx]
      6 

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in wrapper(self, other, axis)
    826             if (not is_scalar(lib.item_from_zerodim(other)) and
    827                     len(self) != len(other)):
--> 828                 raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
    829 
    830             if isinstance(other, ABCPeriodIndex):

ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

**EDIT:**

I ended up finding an edge condition with the original solution when there are collisions on the first/last days of a 30 day window.  I have made some changes to get closer to a robust solution now:

```
start_date_range = pd.date_range('2004-01-01 00:00:00', '12-31-2017 00:00:00', freq='30D')
end_date_range = pd.date_range('2004-01-30 23:59:59', '12-31-2017 23:59:59', freq='30D')

tra = df['transaction_dt'].values[:, None]
idx1 = np.argmax(start_date_range.values < tra, axis=1)
idx2 = np.argmax(end_date_range.values > tra, axis=1)

df['window_start_dt'] = start_date_range[idx1]
df['window_end_dt'] = end_date_range[idx2]
```

However, this is still not working correctly because it only sets 'window_start_dt' to the lowest/first value in the date range: '2004-01-01'.  Good news is it should be faster yet again.

**EDIT:**

I added an answer with the solution to the date collision issue below based on jezrael's answer

**EDIT**

Turns out there was still one more edge case.  Please see jezrael's answer here for the final solution:[Numpy: conditional np.where replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765551/numpy-conditional-np-where-replace/47766753?noredirect=1#comment82518385_47766753)

Comment: Which line exactly produces the error?

Comment: df['window_start_dt'] = df['transaction_dt'].apply(find_window_start_date) and then from further on the trace window_start_date_idx = np.argmax(x < start_date_period.end_time)

Comment: Please post the complete Traceback.

Comment: updated with the complete traceback now

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect the data in the except suite --> maybe print `x` and `start_date_period.end_time` to see what they are then try the comparison, with those values, in the shell.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still cannot figure it out after looking into it further.

Comment: You won't get around the *lengths don't match* problem unless you somehow pad the short one. I think you are going to have to make comparisons on individual items - that means using apply. But if you make a Series of `pandas.Periods`, it might make the comparisons easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use [`broadcasting`](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc):

```
start_date_period = pd.period_range('2004-01-01', '12-31-2017', freq='30D')
end_date_period = pd.period_range('2004-01-30', '12-31-2017', freq='30D')

tra = df['transaction_dt'].values[:, None]
idx1 = np.argmax(tra < start_date_period.end_time.values, axis=1)
idx2 = np.argmin(tra > end_date_period.start_time.values, axis=1)

df['window_start_dt'] = start_date_period[idx1]
df['window_end_dt'] = end_date_period[idx2]
print (df)

   customer_id transaction_dt product  price  units window_start_dt  \
0            1     2004-01-02  thing1     25     47      2004-01-01   
1            1     2004-01-17  thing2    150      8      2004-01-01   
2            2     2004-01-29  thing2    150     25      2004-01-01   
3            3     2017-07-15  thing3     55     17      2017-06-21   
4            3     2016-05-12  thing3     55     47      2016-04-27   
5            4     2012-02-23  thing2    150     22      2012-02-18   
6            4     2009-10-10  thing1     25     12      2009-10-01   
7            4     2014-04-04  thing2    150      2      2014-03-09   
8            5     2008-07-09  thing2    150     43      2008-07-08   

  window_end_dt  
0    2004-01-30  
1    2004-01-30  
2    2004-01-30  
3    2017-07-20  
4    2016-05-26  
5    2012-03-18  
6    2009-10-30  
7    2014-04-07  
8    2008-08-06
```

Comment: Wow, this is an amazing optimization!  I get a 110x speed up compared to the original, row-wise apply.  I had forgotten that broadcasting was an option.

Comment: I have noticed one issue with this approach, unfortunately.  I am getting collisions when transaction_dt occurs on the last day of a window like '2004-01-30' and the first day like '2004-0-31'.  Do you see a solution to that?  Thanks again!

Comment: I check it and I have question, what is desired output? Is possible some dates outside ranges `start_date_period` and `end_date_period` ? Because the best is filter problematic values and set them manually. And there is 3 possibilities  - `NaT`, some scalar dates (min or max in `start_date_period` or dates are not changed - only copied). Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Thanks!  Sure for example if I have a transaction_dt of  '2004-01-30' it is currently being put into the wrong window: window_start_dt:'2004-01-31' and window_end_dt:'2004-01-30'.  This should be in the window_start_dt:'2004-01-01' and window_end_dt:'2004-01-30'.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example data change and a new approach I have been trying that seems to be close now.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I figured out the fix and added an answer.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

I actually found a particularly clever fix for the date collision issue which is just a small change from @jezrael's fantastic answer:

It occurred to me that start_date_range and end_date_range have the exact same number of elements and that, in this specific case, you can just reuse the index created from end_date_range and apply it via np.take to start_date_range to get the correct intervals every time:

```
start_date_range = pd.date_range('2004-01-01 00:00:00', '12-31-2017 00:00:00', freq='30D')
end_date_range = pd.date_range('2004-01-30 23:59:59', '12-31-2017 23:59:59', freq='30D')

tra = df['transaction_dt'].values[:, None]
idx = np.argmax(end_date_range.values > tra, axis=1)

df['window_start_dt'] = np.take(start_date_range, idx)
df['window_end_dt'] = end_date_range[idx]
```

It is also even faster now!

Comment: it turns out that this was not quite right in the end.  @jezrael provided the final necessary tweak so look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765551/numpy-conditional-np-where-replace/47766753?noredirect=1#comment82518385_47766753

Answer (score 0):

I'll sidestep the error you are getting for mismatching lengths.

This still uses `.apply` so it may not be what you want, but maybe simplifying it will help:

Make a column of [pandas.Period](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Period.html)'s with a month frequency.

```
df['window'] = df.transaction_dt.apply(pd.Period, freq='M')

> df
=>            transaction_dt product  price  units  window
customer_id                                             
1               2004-01-02  thing1     25     47 2004-01
1               2004-01-17  thing2    150      8 2004-01
2               2004-01-29  thing2    150     25 2004-01
3               2017-07-15  thing3     55     17 2017-07
3               2016-05-12  thing3     55     47 2016-05
4               2012-02-23  thing2    150     22 2012-02
4               2009-10-10  thing1     25     12 2009-10
4               2014-04-04  thing2    150      2 2014-04
5               2008-07-09  thing2    150     43 2008-07
```

Each Period has a `start_time` and `end_time` attribute which is easy to use

```
>   df.window.dt.start_time
=> customer_id
1   2004-01-01
1   2004-01-01
2   2004-01-01
3   2017-07-01
3   2016-05-01
4   2012-02-01
4   2009-10-01
4   2014-04-01
5   2008-07-01
Name: window, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If you really need a start and end column;

```
df['start'] = df.window.dt.start_time
df['end'] = df.window.dt.end_time

>   df.head()
=>             transaction_dt product  price  units  window      start        end
customer_id                                                                   
1               2004-01-02  thing1     25     47 2004-01 2004-01-01 2004-01-31
1               2004-01-17  thing2    150      8 2004-01 2004-01-01 2004-01-31
2               2004-01-29  thing2    150     25 2004-01 2004-01-01 2004-01-31
3               2017-07-15  thing3     55     17 2017-07 2017-07-01 2017-07-31
3               2016-05-12  thing3     55     47 2016-05 2016-05-01 2016-05-31
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd like to be able to utilize arbitrary date ranges I can define instead on calendar dates.  This is much faster though.